Automatically-create-jira-ticket-from-centreon-alerts using open tickets
I have already implemented the “manual” way to send incident tickets with open ticket in centreon monitoring system to Jira but I am also looking for the best method to implement the “automatic way”.
I'm using Centreon Open Tickets (Version centreon-open-tickets-23.10).
It has been configured with rules to create ticket on our Jira infra.
… we can now open a ticket manually  from the’Custom View’ page… this iw working Well.
But now we would like that tickets are created automatically when a Centreon Services reaches it critical hard State.
To do this, I need to configure a Notification Command : but its means that we must to know the syntax on how to create a ticket in command line.
On our poller we installed this package:
Package centreon-plugin-Notification-Centreon-Opentickets-Api-20240311-143354.el9.noarch
It provides this plugin : ‘/usr/lib/centreon/plugins/centreon_notification_centreon_opentickets_api.pl’
The modes availables are .
close-host
close-service
open-host
open-service
… So we should be able to create a ticket in command line with this plugin, but I cannot find the correct Syntax.
Does it work for any of you please ? And how to implement it ?
thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
